# How to print clean string from JSON list // Dict?

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

so I have some problem to find how to print a clean string from JSON list // Dict files.
I tried .join, .split method but it doesnt seem to work. Thank for the help guys

My code:

```
import json

with open("user.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for person in data["person"]:
    print(person)
```

The JSON file

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "Country": "Montreal",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "Country": "Laval",
      "Gender": "Male"
    }
  ]
}
```

The print output (Which is not the correct format I want)

```
{'name': 'Peter', 'Country': 'Montreal', 'Gender': 'Male'}
{'name': 'Alex', 'Country': 'Laval', 'Gender': 'Male'}
```

I want to have the output print format to be like this:

```
Name: Peter
Country: Montreal
Gender:Male
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access values using their keys as follow

```
import json

with open("user.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for person in data["person"]:
    print(f'Name: {person["name"]}')
    print(f'Country: {person["Country"]}')
    print(f'Gender: {person["Gender"]}')
```

Result:

```
Name: Peter
Country: Montreal
Gender: Male
Name: Alex
Country: Laval
Gender: Male
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all the attributes in the person dictionary (with no exceptions) you can use:

```
for person in data["person"]:
    for k, v in person.items():
        print(k, ':', v)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for person in data["person"]:
    print(f"Name: {person['name']}")
    print(f"Country: {person['Country']}")
    print(f"Gender: {person['Gender']}")
```

for python3.6+